# porting iphone simple calculation app to mac os x app

Tags: iphone, macos

I have iPhone application, which is very simple.

Now i want to turn that application into a Mac OS X app. I have knowledge in developing mobile app I already developed android and iPhone apps.

I'm new to desktop application kindly guide me what is the different between iPhone API and Mac OS X API.
What are the things I should study and how hard is this ? [I already read this](http://www.quadtonerip.com/Tutorial.pdf),
 I need little bit more info.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a super beginner with objective c but what I have seen so far the only difference is some of the GUI objects. But keep in mind I'm  a super noob so I haven't seen much